# Choose browser to launch when debugging ASP.net (Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio, browser

Is there anyway to have Visual studio start up a certain browser when running asp.net project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open any Web Form
2. File->Browse With...
3. Select from the list and hit "Set as Default"

Answer (score 2):

yes

1. navigate to any aspx file in solution explorer
2. Right click browse
3. with and set your default browser

See [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/18/430943.aspx)